# serenity xml file is not created when executed with gradle

Tags: gradle, serenity-bdd

Can anyone tell me why the serenity xml file is not getting generated when executed script with gradle.

html files, SERENITY-JUNIT.xml, index.html is getting created but .xml file is not getting created.

build.gradle

```
repositories {    
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
repositories {
mavenLocal()
jcenter {
url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
}
}

dependencies {
classpath("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.2.2-rc.5")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator' 

jar {
baseName = 'gs-gradle'
version =  '0.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:1.2.2-rc.5'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:1.2.2-rc.5'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-jbehave:1.19.0'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.2.2-rc.5'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.22'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.10'
    compile 'com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.10'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    compile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.lambdaj:lambdaj:2.3.3'
    compile 'org.scream3r:jssc:2.8.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-exec:1.3'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
    compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.54'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
 }

task testAudioAlarm(type: Test)
{ 
description 'Runs the Alarm recording BDD tests.' 
scanForTestClasses = false 
maxParallelForks = 1 
forkEvery = 1 
include '**/AMSTestSuite' 
}

gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
```

command i used to execute script "gradle clean test aggregate"

Comment: Can you show your POM and how you call your program?

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.2.2-rc.5")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'

task testAudioAlarm(type: Test) {
    description 'Runs the Alarm recording BDD tests.'
    scanForTestClasses = false
    maxParallelForks = 1
    forkEvery = 1
    include '**/AMSTestSuite'
}

gradle clean test aggregate

Comment: Please edit your question and add that. This is barely readable.